# solving this equation $\sin x-\cos x=1/\sqrt2$

Tags: trigonometry

I need some help on solving this equation:

$$\sin x-\cos x=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

If I do $\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ and then $\cos x=t$ but don't get anything.
Or $\sin x-\cos x=1/√2)/√2$
Or $\sin x-\cos x=1/√2)*√2$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698964/solve-a-trigonometric-equation-sqrt3-sinx-cosx-sqrt2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Square both sides, then use Pythagorean and double-angle identities. Don't forget to verify potential solutions in the *original* equation!

Comment: What to do when i get 1-sin2x=1/2

Comment: You can rearrange that to get $$\sin2x=\frac12.$$ Now, for which angles $\theta$ is $\sin\theta=\frac12?$

Comment: 30°, but when i come to solutions can i do 2x=π/6+2kπ , 12x=π+12kπ, x=π/12+kπ

Comment: That doesn't quite tell the whole story. Rather, we can say that $\theta=\frac\pi6+2k\pi$ or $\theta=\frac{5\pi}6+2k\pi$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z.$ Then we *can* conclude that $x=\frac\pi{12}+k\pi$ or $x=\frac{5\pi}{12}+k\pi$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: It would be more beneficial, though, to say that there is some $m\in\Bbb Z$ for which $x=\frac\pi{12}+2m\pi$ or $x={5\pi}{12}+2m\pi$ or $x=\frac{13\pi}{12}+2m\pi$ or $x=\frac{17\pi}{12}+2m\pi.$ (Do you see why we can say this?) However, we still need to check these potential solutions in the original equation, since our squaring may have introduced false solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use $$\sin(x)=\cos(\tfrac \pi2 -x)$$ and

$$\cos(A)+\cos(B)=2\cos\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A-B}2$$

to get

$$
\sin(x)-\cos(x)=\cos(\tfrac \pi2 -x)+\cos(\pi+x)=2\cos(\tfrac{3\pi}4)\cos(\tfrac\pi4+x)=-\sqrt2\cos(\tfrac\pi4+x)
$$
Now apply $\cos(\pm\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi)=-\frac12$.

Comment: How if sinx=cos(90+x) ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter : Just apply trigonometric theorems, $\cos(90°+x)=\cos(90°)\cos(x)-\sin(90°) \sin(x)=-\sin(x)$. What exactly did you want to express?

Comment: Now apply $\cos(\pm\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi)=-\frac12$. Why $-2\pi/3$ included?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter : I assumed that the task was to find all solutions, each value inside $(-1,1)$ is taken twice per period, thus $$\frac\pi4+x=\pm\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi.$$

Comment: Cos -2pi/3 is = 1/2 ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter : The point to the angle $-2\pi/3$ is in the third quadrant, both sine and cosine values are negative there. Also, cosine is an even function, $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100590/discussion-between-lifeforbetter-and-dr-lutz-lehmann).

Comment: $$
\sin(x)-\cos(x)=\cos(\tfrac \pi2 - x)+\cos(\pi-x)=2\cos(\tfrac{3\pi}4-x)\cos(-\tfrac\pi4)=\sqrt2\cos(\tfrac{3\pi}4-x)
$$ how about this?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter : Yes, that also works. Might be a bit more straightforward. The solution of course does not change, $$x-\frac{3\pi}4=\pm\frac\pi3+2k\pi,$$ add $\pi$ to both sides to get the previous solution form.